# SQLiteDatabase.delete() and whereArgs strange behaviour

Tags: android, sqlite

Based on the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DeleteDbRow), I have an `SQLiteDatabase` query for deletion as follows:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=MyHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String[] whereArgs={"1","1"};

db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN1+"=? AND "+COLUMN2+"=?",whereArgs);
```

The above query has no effect on the underlying database table.

However, deletion succeeds if I change the above query to:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN1+"=1 AND "+COLUMN2+"=1",null);
```

without using the deletion arguments(`whereArgs`).

This leads me to believe that there's something wrong with proper substitution of the `?`s with the corresponding arguments in `whereArgs`. What's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you need to match `INTEGER` `1` and `delete(...)` arguments are used as `TEXT`.

If you are using numeric arguments, you better uses SQL command concatenation, as you did second time.

With some caution, you can workaround using following:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN1"=CAST(? AS INT) AND "+COLUMN2+"=CAST(? AS INT)", whereArgs);
```

or

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "CAST("+COLUMN1" AS TEXT)=? AND CAST("+COLUMN2+" AS TEXT)=?", whereArgs);
```

Use caution because `CAST(? AS INT)` with invalid numeric string will return `0`.

Comment: I realized that it had something to do with casts. However my problem was that I had not specified any data type (storage class) for `COLUMN2`. That's why it probably defaulted to using the type of my `whereArgs` (i.e. `TEXT`). Modifying the column with data type `INTEGER` did the trick. (I didn't need a `CAST` as you said). Nevertheless, thanks!